# Localization not working for XIB file in XCode 6

Tags: xcode, string, localization, internationalization, xib

I have created a XIB file which I am loading programmatically using initWithNibName. It contains an UILabel and UITextField. Via IB I have created the necessary strings files (German, English):

HelpView0.xib
  HelpView0.xib (base)
  HelpView0.strings (English)
  HelpView0.strings (German)

I am using base localization (development language: English). Issue: When I run the app it always pulls English texts, although the device language is German (same issue in Simulator).

Generally, my storyboard localization using strings file works well. I have tried deleting the app and emptying caches, without success. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same here. For now I use localized XIB files where I have to, because some of my xib's are working properly with .strings files. Sad thing that this bug was found almost year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484066/localization-strings-file-not-working-with-xib-in-xcode-5?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6 you need to select "Use Auto Layout". If you do that the strings file for the language running will be used without having to convert it into an XIB file.